# How to check whether entered element is present in Text box

Tags: robotframework

**How to check whether entered element is present in Text box.**

input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" value="Acterna
 Corp." name="name" maxlength="255" data-bv-field="name"

Element Text Should Be xpath=.//*[@name='name']    ${store}

It is giving error in console. no value it says. but entered in text box ,how to check whether the entered text is right with xpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Get Value keyword to read textbox:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${search text}   robot framework

*** Test Cases ***
StackOverflow
    Open Browser       http://www.google.com/    Chrome    
    Input Text         lst-ib    ${search text}
    ${box text}=       Get Value    lst-ib
    Should Be Equal    ${search text}    ${box text}
    Close All Browsers
```

Comment: Its not fetching value after the form is  saved.                                              ${storeweb}= Getting Random Text website.txt
Input Text id=website ${storeweb}                                                    Click Element xpath=.//*[@id='btnSave']                                        Element Should Contain xpath=.//*[@id='website'and @value='${storeweb}'] ${storeweb}                                                     Its giving error saying but its text was ''

Comment: When giving beforing submitting the form,                                                    ${getwebvalue}= Get Value id=website
Should Be Equal  ${getwebvalue} ${storeweb}.                               its validating

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem from comments but this looks like a different problem. Can you submit a new question for this?